# Does a random variable converge to $0$ in probability with converging expectation?

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative random variable, with its expectation converging to $0$

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{E(X_n)}=0
$$

And $\forall a>0$, according to Markov's inequality

$$
P(X_n\ge a)\le \frac{E(X_n)}{a}
$$

Because of the converging expectation and the arbitrariness of $a$, does $X_n$ converge to $0$ in probability?

And what if $E(X_n)=O(\sqrt{1/n})$, is the asymptotic efficiency of $X_n$ also $O(\sqrt{1/n})$?Does the variance matter?

Comment: For the first part, convergence in mean does imply convergence in probability, for the reason you give

Comment: @Henry That's great, thanks. What about the second part? As I know, if $E(X_n)$ is $O(n^d)$ and $Var(X_n)$ is $O(n^f)$ then $X_n$ is $O(n^g)$, where $g=\max{(d,f/2)}$. The asymptotic efficiency of variance matters. But it seems like it's a special case here according to the paper I recently read.